# Why won't my CD drive eject?

Tags: windows-10, optical-drive

My computer seems to have developed a rather puzzling behavior.

My DVD reader/writer drive no longer ejects it's tray when pushing the eject button.  At first I assumed this was just due to a failed button on the drive itself but then I noticed something strange.  As soon as I open up File Explorer to *This PC*, the drive will open.

The best explanation I can come up with for this behavior is that perhaps something is locking the drive and opening up *This PC* manages to release the lock, but I cannot think of anything I have which would do that.  In addition I even tried logging out of all user accounts and the drive will still not open until someone logs in.

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem and know of a solution?

**Additional notes**

- The PC has been restarted several times between when I first noticed the issue and now.
- The eject seems to be triggered by any drive enumeration. Opening/Refreshing *Disk Management* will trigger it, as will running *diskpart* (or *list volume/disk* from within diskpart).
- Time between pushing the eject button and opening *This PC* seems to be irrelevant. To test I pushed the eject button, then left for about 5 minutes and came back.  As soon as I opened *This PC* the tray ejected.
- I have two optical drives.

  - **F:** is a LG Blu-ray reader/writer and works fine.
  - **G:** is a HP DVD reader/writer and is the trouble drive.
- OS is Windows 10 Pro.  I did a format/clean install back in December.
- I'm mostly just curious about the cause of the issue. The workaround to get the drive open is easy, and the drive works fine otherwise.

Comment: This is indeed strange, it opens up normally whenever "This PC" window in the explorer is open you say, but cannot open up otherwise? This sounds like it could be some funky driver error. But, I am pretty sure something must have caused it to start behaving like this (if it didn't do so in the past) so try to trace back what you did up until this started happening. Maybe even try system restore to a point where it did work.

Comment: I suspect something doing a drive enumeration will cause it to open.  If _This PC_ is already open it won't open until I close and re-open it (or just switch to another view and back).  I'm not sure exactly how long it's been since it started.  I only recently realized the connection, previously I just assumed it was being slow to open.

Comment: Does the tray return smoothly or is there a similar issue there? Does the motor engage when you initially press the button?

Comment: The tray retracts normally with a single button push.  When trying to eject the tray there is a faint hum/clicking sound that starts and persists until the drive finally ejects.